# unlimited search with google search api for dotnet

Tags: vb.net, google-api

I just start to get familiar about google search api and It's really a good thing and I could use it a lot. but when I test it in visual basic , I see it's limited and you can't search more than 100 query a day. Is there any way to search more?

here is my code:

```
    Dim client As New Google.API.Search.GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com")
    Dim results As IList(Of Google.API.Search.IWebResult) = client.Search("site:uploadbaz.com " + TextBox1.Text, 5)

    For Each result As IWebResult In results
            ListBox1.Items.Add(result.Url)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(result.Content)
    Next
```

Comment: That is one of the things I pointed out to you in your other post, though I thought it was 1000 searches per day. No matter.  I suspect you may have to pay if you want to perform more than the specified number.  (PS: Though in this case you don't need to, you may want to consider using the concatenation operator `&` instead of `+` in your code - `"site:uploadbaz.com " + TextBox1.Text`).

Comment: @Westie How could I use this search code twice ? because it says object null reference..